# facebook profile picture url not passing in NSURL

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, nsurl

i am trying to pass profile pic url which is in the formate

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hpe-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-1/c1.0.720/p7720/1364291238051_6773172187152486924_n.jpg?oh=6fda2708e5c1a5de47263&oe=585DC8CF&__gda__=1482408d4fc8e65486e8e1c269af042
```

but when i pass it like

```
NSString *fbpicurl = @"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hpe-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-1/c1.0.720/p7720/1364291238051_6773172187152486924_n.jpg?oh=6fda2708e5c1a5de47263&oe=585DC8CF&__gda__=1482408d4fc8e65486e8e1c269af042";

NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"profilepic=%@",fbpicurl];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.com"];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

when i pass it this way url do not pass completely it just cut of where if founds `&` right after `oh=6fda2708e5c1a5de47263` please help me how can i pass complete url string.

Comment: `NSString *fbpicurl = @"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hpe-ak-xtp1/v/t1.0-1/c1.0.720/p7720/1364291238051_6773172187152486924_n.jpg?oh=6fda2708e5c1a5de47263&oe=585DC8CF&__gda__=1482408d4fc8e65486e8e1c269af042";
` May be you are just missing `@""` for string.

Comment: that is obvious buddy you can not create a NSSTRING without @""

Comment: you need to encode this string when you are creating post string

Comment: @Bhupesh can you tell me how to encode

Comment: @VixHunk Please see the answer of NSSam he has write the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First encode your url string.

```
 + (NSString *) addPercentEscapesAndReplaceAmpersand: (NSString *) yourUrlString
    {
        NSString *encodedString = [yourUrlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        return [encodedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"&" withString: @"%20"];
    }
```

Then used string for url by using `NSURL URLWithString`